# Jira curl issue create ends with error HTTP 415

Tags: json, curl, terminal, jira

I am trying to create issue in project via curl, but it ends with 415 error which I don't know why as I am pasting only text there.

```
curl -D- -s -u email:api_key -X POST --data "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\": \"PROBLEM\"},\"summary\": \"REST ye merry gentlemen.\",\"description\": \"Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API\",\"issuetype\": {\"name\": \"Outage\"}}}" https://company.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/
```

Output:

```
HTTP/2 415 
date: Tue, 27 Sep 2022 11:14:10 GMT
content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
server: globaledge-envoy
timing-allow-origin: *
x-arequestid: bbc0506d-8e7c-442f-a180-46632081b6a5
set-cookie: atlassian.xsrf.token=BAHL-ME69-JQ45-BS4O_929b97ddce3a4de2b40abbd3d2817ff133d29cee_lin; path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
x-aaccountid: 62b303db84d73c7201680c55
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 56
expect-ct: report-uri="https://web-security-reports.services.atlassian.com/expect-ct-report/atlassian-proxy", max-age=86400
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
atl-traceid: b0b3324454c29763
report-to: {"endpoints": [{"url": "https://dz8aopenkvv6s.cloudfront.net"}], "group": "endpoint-1", "include_subdomains": true, "max_age": 600}
nel: {"failure_fraction": 0.001, "include_subdomains": true, "max_age": 600, "report_to": "endpoint-1"}
vary: Accept-Encoding
```

I don't understand why I am getting 415 message from Jira.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTTP 415** means Unsupported Media Type (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415).

Basically, you have to tell JIRA you are sending a JSON. Just add:

```
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

to your curl command.
Also another note you may want to use
**rest/api/3/issue/** instead of **rest/api/2/issue/**

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issues/#api-rest-api-3-issue-createmeta-get

and if you got some error message like:

```
Operation value must be an Atlassian Document (see the Atlassian Document Format)
```

change your "description" field to something like this:

```
"description": {
    "type": "doc",
    "version": 1,
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "paragraph",
            "content": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For example

```
curl -i -u nanana@gmail.com:xxxxxx  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST --data '{"fields": {"project": {"key": "RW"}, "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.", "description": {"type": "doc", "version": 1, "content": [{"type": "paragraph", "content": [{"type": "text", "text": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API"} ] } ] }, "issuetype": {"name": "Task"} } }' https://s50600822.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue

{"id":"10013","key":"RW-6","self":"https://s50600822.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10013"}
```